# Centralized SSL Certificate is not working with wild card

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, iis-8.5

I have two sites which are ****.twsstaging.com and ****.testrdcstg.com. I have wildchar certificates for both the sites. 
I am using IIS 8.5 in Windows server 2012R2. I have a **SINGLE** site configured in IIS which resolve to both these domains. 
Now I need to add SSL to these sites. I have tried with adding multiple bindings on 443 which leades to use only one certificate.
Since IIS is 8.5 i am not able to give *.twsstaging.com or *.testrdcstg.com as header values in bindings. I have tried this in IIS 10.0 and succeeded as wildchar hostname entries are allowed.

This is the error while trying to add wildchar hostname in binding

[image]

I tried (Server Name Indication)SNI as well which also failed due to above error as i cannot give wildchar host names.

Now I am trying to use a Central Certificate Store(CCS) with wildchar. Below are my setup screenshots

**One Certificate details**

[image]

**Central Certificate store**

[image]

**IIS Binding**

[image]

[image]

**I added an entry in \System32\drivers\etc\hosts file as well**

[image]

**But if I am browsing HTTPS:// first site is showing 404 page and other is showing privacy error message**

[image]

**It looks like still both domains are loading with one certificate.**

[image]

Earlier,When I added these bindings normally HTTPS was working fine first sites and same privacy error for second one.

So here the ask is Can I achieve this in IIS 8.5?

I have tried normal bindings,SNI and CCS approaches on same 443 port.

Is there any way to achieve it either though CCS or through different port?

Comment: IIS 8.5 does not support wildcard host names like IIS 10. You have to configure multiple HTTPS bindings manually for the subdomains.

Comment: Its not possible to setup bindings for each sub domains as sub domains are huge in numbers.

So what is wild card certficate is doinng with centralized cetficate as they mentioned to name it by _

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability

Comment: They mentioned that simply because wildcard certificates have been long supported (even in IIS 5 and 6), and you need to know how to configure that. However, wild host name is not supported until IIS 10. Upgrade to IIS 10 if you can, or use some workarounds such as use two IP addresses and bind two certificates as IP mapping, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: Is it possible to add two bindings with different certificate on different port on same IP address.

1.1.1.1:443 first certficate 
1.1.1.1:8443 Second certficate 

Is it possible?

Comment: The web browsers do like ports other than 443, and you will see warnings.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li. I may need to upgrade my IIS. Let me see whether I can do anything over Load Balancer

Answer (score 0):

ran into this a few years ago and again today after an outage where we had to change the IP bindings.

1. use a random host name like 123.com
2. save the binding
3. edit C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
4. replace 123.com with * and save
5. restart iis site